# How to change an image based on page url in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a header which I'm calling through a `cfinclude`. However, I want to be able to change an image on the header based off the page url. So if you are in index.html, use this image a and if not, use this image b. I know nothing about ColdFusion, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the cgi variables

```
<cfif cgi.script_name eq 'index.cfm'>
   <img scr="imga.jpg">
<cfelse>
   <img src="imgb.jpg">
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 2):

check `CGI` scope, and use basic `<cfif>`

by default, only *.cfm is mapped to Coldfusion.  So your index.html should really be index.cfm.